# IBM Watson Conversation: How to capture and retrieve a list of values in a variable

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have a dialog where users can enter one or more country names.
How do I retrieve the values from the entity defined to store the responses.

Example :
Entity : Country

> Question : Where did you travel to?
>    Answer :  Africa, Thailand and
>   China.

How can I capture these 3 values in a list entity?

Comment: Are you using the sys-location entity?

Comment: Yes. Just can't seem to get the response back that there are 3 values captured. Kept displaying the first value. Will try your suggestion posted below tomorrow morning.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Henrik is right, just to add to that,
What he said will return them in an array, if you do

```
"countries": "<? entities['sys-location'] .toString() ?>"
```

you will get a comma separated list of the locations returned.

Answer (score 0):

@sys-location entity in System Entities extracts location from the conversation. (Note: Ensure that you have switched on that entity as shown below)

[image]

You can now see that location has been extracted from conversation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [system entity for locations, `@sys-location`](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/system-entities.html#sys-location). You need to turn that capability on for your workspace. See the wizard for entity creations.

In your dialog node where you want to capture the input in a list, you can assign those countries to a [context variable](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html#context). Switch to the JSON editor to edit variables. Then do something like:

```
"context": {
    "countries": "<? entities['sys-location'] ?>"
  },
```

See my [collection of examples for context processing](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/watson-conversation-variables) for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Its Quite Simple. Use

```
"countries": "@sys-location.values"
```

It will list all @sys-location values in array form.